# Joining two tables on two different columns depending on the condition

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to add Tran_type '1' to a working query.

I have 3 tables: A, B, and C. Table A and Table B join together on a.batch = b.batch, while Table A and Table C join together on a.sequence = c.sequence. There are no identifying columns equal between Tables B and C.

I need to pull Tran_type '1' from Table C into batch. This transaction type only pulls through when Table A joins to Table C on a.sequence = c.ref_sequence. I need it to pull through along with the rest of the transaction query output.

The following is a very simplified version of the query in question:

```
With Commission (SELECT FROM JOIN)

SELECT batch.*, c.id, c.payment, c.commission, c.tran_type

FROM Commission c, 
     (SELECT FROM JOIN a.batch = b.batch AND b.tran <> 1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT FROM JOIN a.batch = b.batch AND b.tran <> 1 AND a.tran_reason IS NOT NULL
      ) batch

WHERE batch.sequence = c.sequence
```

I have tried different variations of joins to include a.Tran_type '1' outputs into the existing query, including:

```
WHERE 
batch.sequence = (CASE WHEN c.Tran_type = 1 THEN c.ref_sequence 
                       WHEN c.Tran_type <> 1 THEN c.sequence)

WHERE batch.sequence = c.sequence 
  OR (batch.sequence = c.ref_sequence and c.Tran_type = 1)
```

Currently the output is as follows in regards to transaction:

```
+----------+-----+---------+------------+-----------+
| Batch_No | ID  | Payment | Commission | Tran_Type |
+----------+-----+---------+------------+-----------+
|        1 |  43 |     100 |        .14 |         2 |
|        2 | 354 |      50 |        .07 |         2 |
|        3 | 765 |      75 |        .20 |         2 |
+----------+-----+---------+------------+-----------+
```

The output should be:

```
+----------+-----+---------+------------+-----------+
| Batch_No | ID  | Payment | Commission | Tran_Type |
+----------+-----+---------+------------+-----------+
|        1 |  43 |     100 |        .14 |         2 |
|        2 | 354 |      50 |        .07 |         2 |
|        3 | 765 |      75 |        .20 |         2 |
|        4 | 987 |      25 |        .05 |         1 |
|        5 |  87 |     125 |        .25 |         1 |
+----------+-----+---------+------------+-----------+
```

Let me know if I can further clarify.

Comment: Personally, I prefer seeing sample data so that I could try it myself. Without it, just a lucky guess: did you try **outer join**? Looks like that, looking at difference between current & desired output.

Comment: @littlefoot, I figured it out by adding another UNION ALL statement and leaving conditions as stated above. Thank you.

Comment: OK. I'm glad you made it; thank you for letting us know.